# Why i get System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

My model is defined like this:

```
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        //[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string ODID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите ИНН")]
        public long AuthorityINN { get; set; }
        public int AuthorityID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите наименование набора данных")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите краткое описание")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите полное описание")]
        public string FullDescription { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        //public int OwnerID {get;set;}
        public Periodicity Periodicity { get; set; }
        public string KeyWords { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public bool HasGeo { get; set; }
        public long Reviews { get; set; }
        public long Downloads { get; set; }
}
```

But I catch a `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException` exception with a message:

> Define key for this EntityType.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you provide more info? When does it happen? Is ODID set for the object that you are trying to save?

Comment: It happen when i try create model. Yes, ODID is set.

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce the issue with provided model, it works fine for me. It might be connected with another entity or something else. Can you provide stack trace for this exception with full text instead of short one?

Comment: Full stacktrace in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01cfe0750d89fc609798)

Comment: this trace is unrelated to Entity Framework exception thrown, need to see what Entity Framework says - stacktrace and message. Did you check your DB has ODID as a primary key for real? Also can you provide simplified code for your controller method and line that causes this?